# Validating an inputted email and password in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, email

What I want to do is establish a function in JavaScript that will validate an inputted email and password, that checks the inputted email to make sure it has at least 2-3 characters after the last period in the string (for .com, .org, .ca, etc.) and that the string has at least one '@' symbol in it.

As for checking the password, I want the function to check that it has at least one lowercase and one uppercase letter, at least one number, and at least one special character  (!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,~)

Does anyone know what I would have to do to get the regular expression to check the password for at least 1 special character like !, @, *, etc.?

Here's what I have:

```
function validatePassword(password)
{
    var passwordPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
return passwordPattern.test(password)
}

// Validate form
function validate()
{
var email = user.email.value;
if(validateEmail(user.email.value))
    user.validEmail.value = "OK";
else
    user.validEmail.value = "X";
if(validatePassword(user.password.value))
    user.validPassword.text = "OK";
else
    user.validPassword.text = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can user Regular Expressions for both cases. 
As for the e-mail, you can read more here: http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-address-using-javascript-regular-expression/
As for the password check, I'd recommend reading this: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/

Here's the validation of password:

```
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" onblur="validate"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtPassword = null;

    var txtPassword_Blur = function(e) {
        var exp = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
        var validPassword = exp.test($(this).val());
        if(validPassword) {
           alert('valid');
        } else {
           alert('not valid');
        }
    };

    $(function() {
        txtPassword = $("#txtPassword");
        txtPassword.bind("blur", null, txtPassword_Blur);
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** This regular expression doesn't check for special characters. I think it's kind of specific to your definitions, but you can edit the expression and add a list of characters that you'd consider special for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my project of the cross-browser filter of value of the text input element on your web page using JavaScript language: [Input Key Filter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) . You can filter the value as an integer number, a float number, or write a custom filter, such as a phone number filter. See an example of code of input an email and password:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
Email: <input type="email" id="Email" value="username@domain.com"/>
<script>
 CreateEmailFilter("Email", function(event){//onChange event
   inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
   var elementNewInteger = document.getElementById("NewEmail");
   elementNewInteger.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
  
  //onblur event. Use this function if you want set focus to the input element again if input value is NaN. (empty or invalid)
  , function(event){ this.ikf.customFilter(this); }
 );
</script>
 New email: <span id="NewEmail"></span>
<hr>
Password: 
<input type="password" id="Password"
 onchange="javascript: onChangePassword(this)"
 onblur="javascript: this.ikf.customFilter(this)"
/>
<script>
 function onChangePassword(input){
  inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
  if(!input.ikf.customFilter(input))
   return false;
  var elementNewPassword = document.getElementById("NewPassword");
  elementNewPassword.innerHTML = input.value;
 }
 CreatePasswordFilter("Password"
  , function(elementInput, value){//customFilter
//consoleLog("password customFilter. elementInput = " + elementInput + "\n\n" + printStackTrace().join("nn"));

    if(typeof value == 'undefined')
     value = elementInput.value;
     
    var array = value.match(/([^a-zA-Z\d]+)/);
    if(array != null){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Недопустимый символ: " + array[0]
       : "Invalid symbol: " + array[0]
      , elementInput, "uparrowdivred");
     inputKeyFilter.focus(elementInput);
     return false;
    }
    var passwordLengthMin = 6;
    if(value.length < passwordLengthMin){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Пароль должен быть длиннее " + passwordLengthMin + " символов."
       : "The password at least " + passwordLengthMin + " characters."
      , elementInput);
     inputKeyFilter.focus(elementInput);
     return false;
    }
    if(value.match(/(\d+)/i) == null){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Введите хотя бы одну цифру."
       : "The password must contain at least one digit."
      , elementInput, "uparrowdivyellow");
     inputKeyFilter.focus(elementInput);
     return false;
    }
    if(value.match(/([a-z]+)/) == null){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Введите хотя бы одну латинскую букву."
       : "The password must contain at least one letter."
      , elementInput, "uparrowdivyellow");
     inputKeyFilter.focus(elementInput);
     return false;
    }
    if(value.match(/([A-Z]+)/) == null){
     inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
       "Введите хотя бы одну заглавную латинскую букву."
       : "The password must contain at least one upper-case letter."
      , elementInput, "uparrowdivyellow");
     inputKeyFilter.focus(elementInput);
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
/*    
  //, null//onChange
  , function(event){//onChange
    input = this;
    inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
    if(!input.ikf.customFilter(input))
     return false;
    var elementNewPassword = document.getElementById("NewPassword");
    elementNewPassword.innerHTML = input.value;
   }
  //, null//onblur
  , function(event){//onblur
    this.ikf.customFilter(this);
   }
*/    
 );
</script>
 New password: <span id="NewPassword"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page ["Email:" and "Password:" of the example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexp for both of these

```
function validate(form_id,email) {

   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   var address = document.forms[form_id].elements[email].value;
   if(reg.test(address) == false) {

      alert('Invalid Email Address');
      return false;
   }
}
```

for the email (source: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/javascript-validation/)

And use the same method for verifying your Password.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: Note this commonly-quoted pattern isn't a good idea: it will block various valid addresses including users with `+` in their name and the >4-letter TLDs.